# Remove all repeated values in array and leave the ones that don't repeat in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Example: I have an array with repeated values 1 and 2

```
[1,1,2,2,3,4,5]
```

I want the result of that array to be an array of the values that dont repeat.

```
[3,4,5]
```

Comment: Make an object whose properties are the values from the array, and values are the count of repetitions. After you're done, find all the keys with value = 1.

Comment: @Barmar has the method I prefer to use-- quick and dirty, but it gets the job done efficiently.

Comment: @Bergi it's not a duplicate of that question. That will keep one copy of every value, he wants only the values that started with 1 copy.

Comment: i'm trying to use filter function.
`[1,1,2,2,3,4,5].filter(function(c,i,a){
    return (a.indexOf(c) < i);`

but Im not getting anywhere.

Comment: @Barmar Ah, you're right. How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34498659/return-unique-element-that-does-not-have-duplicates-in-an-array then?

Comment: is it always sorted?

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, that's the same, although for some reason the OP's function takes two arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without JQuery, you can use the [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method:

```
var nums = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5]
nums = nums.filter(function(val){
  return nums.indexOf(val)===nums.lastIndexOf(val);
});
// [3,4,5]
```

Otherwise, if in future you want to preserve repeated numbers, you can use:

```
for(var i=0; i<nums.length; i++) if(i!==nums.lastIndexOf(nums[i])) nums.splice(i, 1);
// [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: thanks criz it worked!

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,1,2,2,3,4,5]

arr = arr.filter (function (value, index, array) {
    return array.indexOf (value) == array.lastIndexOf(value);
});

console.log(arr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qducmzqk/